# ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 200 into shape (200,320,240,1)

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to format a numpy array for a convolutional neural network, and I keep getting this error when trying to reshape the array into the desired dimensions with this function.

```
x_train = x_train.reshape(200, 320, 240, 1)
```

Each image has a length of 320 pixels and a width of 240 pixels, and there are 200 of them. Currently the array is formatted like so:

[[....],[.....],[.....]]

where each "sub" array corresponds with the data extracted from each image. However, the function above then reads the array's length as the number of "sub" arrays and not the number of terms. How can I consolidate the subarrays into one larger array like so,

[.....................]

allowing the reshape function to calculate its length based on the number of terms?

I have already tried copying individual terms into the array, but that gives the same error. I have also read all of the other Stack Overflow posts containing the same error.

Currently, this is my data processing script.

```
train_size = 600
test_size = 200

batch_size = 60
num_classes = 2
epochs = 10

img_rows, img_cols = 320, 240


TrainArray = []
for file in os.listdir("C:/Users/aeshon/Desktop/Project2020/Step2/TRAIN/birds"):
    img = imread("C:/Users/aeshon/Desktop/Project2020/Step2/TRAIN/birds/" + file)
    # print("Hi"+str(count))
    new_img = img[:, :, 0]
    TrainArray.append(new_img)
for file in os.listdir("C:/Users/aeshon/Desktop/Project2020/Step2/TRAIN/animals"):
    img = imread("C:/Users/aeshon/Desktop/Project2020/Step2/TRAIN/animals/" + file)
    # print("Hi"+str(count))
    new_img = img[:, :, 0]
    TrainArray.append(new_img)
print("Train Array Synthesis Complete")
x_train = np.asarray(TrainArray)
del TrainArray
print("Array Deleted!")
count = 0
TestArray = []
for file in os.listdir("C:/Users/aeshon/Desktop/Project2020/Step2/TEST/birds"):
    img = imread("C:/Users/aeshon/Desktop/Project2020/Step2/TEST/birds/" + file)
    # print("Hi"+str(count))
    new_img = img[:, :, 0]
    TestArray.append(new_img)
for file in os.listdir("C:/Users/aeshon/Desktop/Project2020/Step2/TEST/animals"):
    img = imread("C:/Users/aeshon/Desktop/Project2020/Step2/TEST/animals/" + file)
    # print("Hi"+str(count))
    new_img = img[:, :, 0]
    TestArray.append(new_img)
print("Test Array Synthesis Complete")
x_test = np.asarray(TestArray)
#print(TestArray)
del TestArray
print("Array Deleted!")

#sys.exit()

x_train = x_train.reshape(train_size, img_rows, img_cols, 1)
x_test = x_test.reshape(test_size, img_rows, img_cols, 1)
```

EDIT: error code

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/aeshon/PycharmProjects/Object_Detector/Model2.py", line 59, in <module>
    x_test = x_test.reshape(-1, img_rows, img_cols, 1)
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 200 into shape (320,240,1)
```

the array currently looks like this (edited for length):

```
[[  2,  13,   0, ...,   0,  16,   0],
 [ 11,  96, 112, ...,  80,  77,  13],
 [  0, 106, 122, ...,  93,  81,   4],

...

[168, 167, 164, ..., 183, 183, 184],
[170, 168, 165, ..., 183, 183, 184],
[171, 169, 165, ..., 183, 184, 184]]
```

Comment: Did you check the shape of `x_train` before reshaping? What does it says? It should be working. The only thing that might be wrong is the number of files you are loading from your disk (or their shape)

Comment: Your method should work.You may have less than 200 images, or number of images could be uncertain. Try x_train = x_train.reshape(-1, 320, 240, 1) . It will reshape to [Numberofimages,320,240,1] . Why don't you share the error code.

Comment: I wrote a script that ensures all images are 320x240. Also, I have pasted the error script in and used your suggestion, Mehmet. The code for some reason shaped to [320,240,1]

Comment: Since your code is fine, there must be some reason in the images. Do print out `x_test.shape` and, if needed, print out `new_img.shape` while appending them to `TestArray`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice!